# I can't seem to transfer a Terraria character and world to a flash drive

Tags: terraria

I'm on macOS High Sierra version 10.13.6 and I can't seem to transfer the character and world to the flash drive. Hoping I could use some help with this and I'll be transferring it to a Windows 10 desktop.

Answer (score 2):

As **Teo** said [here](https://steamcommunity.com/app/105600/discussions/0/541906989403248377):

> Actually I managed to find a way, I don't know if it'll be the same for you guys but it's basically go into your Library > Application Support > and there should be a folder in there called Terraria that has your worlds and players and servers etc

**Another solution:**
If you are playing Terraria 1.3 on Steam: click the cloud icon on the bottom-left of the player/world card. After that, you can access it from any computer.